# How to use SharePoint 2010 STS as Identity Provider

Tags: sharepoint, claims, federation

I want to used SharePoint 2010 STS with the role of an IdentityProvider for a standalone ASP.NET application.

How can I do that?

Update:
My requirement is the following: build and ASP.NET app that uses the users in SharePoint for authentication and provide a SingleSignOn with SharePoint. The app will be opened in a iFrame inside a SP page. If authentication settings in SP change (besides ADFS it will federate over another IdP) ASP.NET app should not suffer changes.
Knowing that SP 2010 provides a STS I want to use it with the role of IdP with passive federation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the STS included in SharePoint is meant to be used as a general purpose IdP. It is more of an RP-STS than anything else. Even if you make it work, it might not be a supported configuration. If you are using AD, a better option is to use ADFS.

Building a (production ready) STS from scratch with WIF is possible, but not a trivial task. So the general recommendation is to use one that is already tested and design for that (e.g. ADFS, ACS on the Microsoft world, or from some other vendor). If you still want to build one, then start with something like StarterSTS or IdentityServer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm also starting ti think that SP STS cannot be used with IdP role. I find it odd. I couldn't find the Federation Metadata, even if from what I know by standard it should be provided...
For my scenario, the only option I see now is to implement my own STS with role of IdP inside SharePoint (as an app or a WCF service) and being into SP context to do the authentication and than redirect.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET you may need to write a Custom STS (For issuing tokens) using WIF.. Here are few articles that might help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/02/17/5-minutes-wif-make-your-asp-net-application-use-test-sts.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2008/11/26/an-identity-provider-and-its-sts-writing-a-custom-sts-with-the-october-beta-of-the-geneva-framework.aspx

Comment: Are you saying that I should create my own STS inside SharePoint? and not using SharePoint STS?

I wanted to use SharePoint STS with passive federation as an IP for my application. I cannot find the Federation Metadata of SharePoint STS...

Comment: I am sorry, but I think you need to add more details in your question. From first look, I thought you need similar implementation in a StandAlone ASP.NET, no SharePoint. That's what I provided. If you are looking for integrating ASP.NET and SP STS authentication. There are various ways to do that. You can use SAML token to exchange authentication details between the application and set it up through federation.